# Why does loop runs 1 or 2 times only when I use rand() function in c++

Tags: c++

I want to generate random test cases for my program, but it crashes after running 1 or 2 times.
I have used rand() function to generate random numbers for random test cases
but it is not running after one or sometimes two times.. and does not generate any random number. The program simply exits.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<ctime>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

long long int naive(long long int arr[],long long int n){
    long long int max=-1;
    for(long long int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(long long int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(arr[i]%arr[j] > max){
                max = arr[i]%arr[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}

long long int efficent(long long int arr[],long long int n){
    long long int max1=0,max2=0;
    for(long long int i=0;i<n;i++){
         if (arr[i] > max1) 
        { 
            max2 = max1; 
            max1 = arr[i]; 
        } 
        else if (arr[i] > max2 && arr[i] != max1) 
            max2 = arr[i]; 
    }
    return max2%max1;
}

int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    long long int count=0;
    int t=10;
    while(t--){
      long long int n;
      n = rand()%10;
      long long int arr[n];
      for(long long int i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i] = rand()%10;
      }
      long long int a,b;
      a = naive(arr,n);
      b = efficent(arr,n);
      if(a == b)
        cout<<"Naive : "<<a<<"\tEfficent : "<<b<<"\n";
      else{
        cout<<"\nNot Equal."<<"\nCount : "<<++count<<endl;
        cout<<"Naive : "<<a<<"\tEfficent : "<<b<<"\n";
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` is highly problematic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is [*barely* random at all](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Comment: Regarding the line: `long long int arr[n];` -- when [I build this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f887c55f96959c7f), I get the warning "ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr' [-Wvla]". Therefore, I suggest you start there. One way would be to replace that line with `std::vector<long long> arr( n );`. For instance, [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b62fa27a4d7fd218).

Comment: Why are you using `long long` for everything?   Seems you could use a more common type for the same result.

Comment: Recommended watching: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: Actually, I am doing a competetive programming problem. Just to test my naive and efficient algorithm I developed this program for multiple test cases.

Comment: I am using ```long long``` in the code because of the constraints provided in the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the memory leaks and not declaring a variable sized array correctly mentioned in the other answer, the issue is that you are performing the mod operation on values that could be 0.  This will force your program to exit.  To fix this, change

```
arr[i] = rand()%10;
```

to something like

```
arr[i] = rand()%10+1;
```

to prevent division by 0.

EDIT: as mentioned by @Michael Dorgan, you should probably do the same for `n`. Change

```
n = rand()%10;
```

to

```
n = rand()%10+1;
```

to prevent 0 length arrays from being allocated.

Comment: Show the line it does this in your answer - the `arr[i]%arr[j]` line or possibly the `max1%max2` line.

Comment: Also, allocating 0 bytes then de-referencing it is also bad and is fixed by this...

Comment: This comment confused me some - its not _this_ mod which is bad when `rand` is used. its the fact that this mod may set `arr[I]` to 0 and a later mod uses that as the RHS.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan feel free to edit post. I can't seem to mention the line where the mod occurs without being too wordy.

Comment: @MikeVine exactly. The values generated here are what is used in the RHS later. Changing these values prevents mod by 0 later.

Comment: Honestly, the whole program is problematic.  Mention `number % 0` is bad.  Mention dynamic array of size 0 is bad.  Mention dynamic array instead of vector or new/delete is bad for leaks.  So much to mention...

Comment: Thanks for telling me about my mistakes. Ill surely take care next time while building such programs.

Answer (score 0):

This code is problematic:

```
while(t--){
    long long int n;
    n = rand()%10;
    long long int arr[n];
    for(long long int i=0;i<n;i++){
    arr[i] = rand()%10;
    }
```

If you need a variable size array, you should use `long long int * arr = new long long int[n];` and `delete[] arr;` before the last closing brace of the `while` block.

Comment: Should mention leaking memory as troublesome as well.  long long to store 0-9 is interesting too.

Comment: Yes, you're perfectly right but that's not the issue in the code right now, as far as I'm understanding it. They are many way to improve this code, starting by adequate type for the data size, using vectors, not using `srand`/`rand` and trying to prove that a O(N^2) is slower than O(N) when N is so small, and taking a modulo of 0, correct indentation...

Comment: lol - yup.  The better thing would have been to have OP go to the debugger on the line of the crash and see if it was divide by 0, like we think, or something else.